# Building Flutter Application on Linux VM

Tags: flutter, cmake

I'm trying to build a flutter application on my linux VM. But everytime I'm running the build command

> flutter run

I'm getting following error message:

```
> flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:545 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:733 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/CMakeLists.txt:25 (pkg_check_modules)


Building Linux application...                                           
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

It dose not say which package was not found. Here are the highlighted lines:

FindPkgConfig.cmake:545

```
if (${_is_required})
```

FindPkgConfig.cmake:731-736

```
  if (NOT DEFINED __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} OR __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} LESS ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION} OR NOT ${_prefix}_FOUND OR
      (NOT "${ARGN}" STREQUAL "" AND NOT "${__pkg_config_arguments_${_prefix}}" STREQUAL "${_module0};${ARGN}") OR
      (    "${ARGN}" STREQUAL "" AND NOT "${__pkg_config_arguments_${_prefix}}" STREQUAL "${_module0}"))
    _pkg_check_modules_internal("${_pkg_is_required}" "${_pkg_is_silent}" ${_no_cmake_path} ${_no_cmake_environment_path} ${_imp_target} ${_imp_target_global} "${_prefix}" ${_pkg_modules})

    _pkgconfig_set(__pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION})
```

Comment: It is always useful to look into the code.. but aren't there messages about missing packages **above** the error message?

Comment: no, sadly not :( that's why I'm confused. Before this message it tolds me the packages I have to install, what I did. But now this...
I updated the log output. You can see the whole log now

Comment: You could look into the line `flutter/CMakeLists.txt:25`. According to the log, it contains call to [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules) function. Its arguments denote names of the packages which are searched.